# Ruby making a web request

Tags: ruby, http, httpwebrequest

Hi this is my very first Ruby program.
I'm trying to write a simple ruby app to make a request to a URL and see if it's available. If it is, it'll print OK and else it'll print false.

This is what I've got so far, can you please assist, do I need to import any libs?

```
class WebRequest

    def initialize(name)
        @name = name.capitalize
    end
    def makeRequest
        puts "Hello #{@name}!"

        @uri = URI.parse("https://example.com/some/path")
        http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
        http.use_ssl = true
        http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE # read into this
        @data = http.get(uri.request_uri)

    end

end

req = WebRequest.new("Archie")
req.makeRequest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've ended up with

```
require 'net/http'

class WebRequest

    def initialize()
        @url_addr = 'http://www.google.com/'
    end
    def makeRequest

        puts ""

        begin  
            url = URI.parse(@url_addr)
            req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
            res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
            http.request(req)
            }

            puts "OK Connected to #{@url_addr} with status code #{res.code}"
        rescue
            puts "Failed to connect to #{@url_addr}"
        end
    end
end

req = WebRequest.new()
req.makeRequest
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is sample code to do any request:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

url = URI.parse('http://www.example.com/index.html')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
  http.request(req)
end
puts res.body
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    gem install httparty
```

then

```
    require 'httparty'
    response = HTTParty.get('https://example.com/some/pathm')
    puts response.body
```

Answer (score 0):

Something simpler:

```
    [1] pry(main)> require 'open-uri'
    => true
    [2] pry(main)> payload = open('http://www.google.com')
    => #<File:/var/folders/2p/24pztc5s63d69hhx81002bq80000gn/T/open-uri20131217-84948-ttwnho>
    [3] pry(main)> payload.inspect
    => "#<Tempfile:/var/folders/2p/24pztc5s63d69hhx81002bq80000gn/T/open-uri20131217-84948-ttwnho>"
    [4] pry(main)> payload.read
```

`payload.read` would return the response body and you can easy use payload as `File` object since it is an instance of `Tempfile`